# How to encode a save game / game state as a string?

Tags: javascript, savegame, json

I'm building an HTML game. For this game I want to implement a save-feature that should work like in some already existing games:

The user can chose `export`, this will create a string, representing the game state (I guess).
This string can be pasted into an `import` input and will load the save game.

I thought about storing the state in a JSON, minifying it, stringifying and encoding it in Base64.
But I don't think this is a good idea, users could easily cheat in this game by decoding the string, changing whatever they want, encoding it again and loading this string.

I already tried generating save files in games with this feature and decoding them in Base64 which didn't work, so I assume they use a different encoding.

How can I encode the JSON like this?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. This seems like a possible duplicate of [How do I implement a retro-style password-based "savegame" system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104562/how-do-i-implement-a-retro-style-password-based-savegame-system) If you feel your question differs or the answers there won't work for you, please consider editing to emphasize the differences.

Comment: Also, any time you hand over game state data to players, there's an opportunity for it to be misused. It's possible to make this harder for them (hashing, etc) but in most normal circumstances, you won't be able to prevent it all together.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful not related directly but should help, as the language is only tool
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/io/encrypting_save_games.html

Comment: If this is a single-player game, why does it matter if users cheat? It takes *some* effort and knowledge to decode a string, find which data changes what in the game, so if someone decides to do that, why not let them?

Comment: If this is an HTML game that runs its game loop entirely in the browser then the player is already free to use their browser's Javascript console to tamper with your game at run time. They don't even need the save data to cheat.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to be sure they won't misuse save data don't give it to them in any form :)**

You may give them some key to save stored on for example [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products) or [playfab](https://playfab.com/) that they can recover by entering it or just create authentication mechanism that will connect them to all their data saved in cloud.

**If you don't really care just give them that JSON.**

If someone will want to decode it he will just find your part of code that decodes it on frontend. You may want to make it a little bit harder for them by hiding decoding mechanism on server but that just turns it into more fun for hacking.

Comment: I disagree with giving raw JSON. Not giving raw JSON for end user will prevent most CASUAL players from adjusting its data. Furthermore, making it more challenging to hack actually draws longer attention from those who actually knows how to do it (win for you as well).

Comment: @TomasŠvedas maybe using some asymetrical encoding for data that requires server side for decoding could be a little bit harder for hackers and still give ability to keep local copy of game data that is to hard to crac for casual players but at some point if hacker cracs it he can create tool for casual players to edit this data

Comment: still, think of it as free promotion. Now imagine, your game is hard to hack, hackers discuss, people looks for tools, your game name shows in search - free promotion. Then, the hack is released, people are posting and sharing the hack - also promotion. Those, who hack, will always hack, so you can try turning that as a benefit for you.